# Keycloak Docker HTTPS required

Tags: docker, https, keycloak

I have initialized https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ on my Digital Ocean Docker Droplet.

`$docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e -p 8080:8080 KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD={password with upcase etc.} jboss/keycloak`

> success

Everything worked well and the server started in the Droplets IP address on a port :8080.

Problems started when I entered the admin console from the UI in the URL. There was a message: "HTTPS required". This was a real issue and the only solution I have found is to login to the Keycloak from the console and to change the setting of HTTPS=required from admin console without the UI.

I then opened the bash for my Docker container :

`$docker exec -it keycloak bash`

> success

As I entered my command to login in the keycloak/bin folder:

`cd keycloak/bin`

`keycloak/bin $./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://<droplet IP>:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password {password with upcase etc.}`

> the bash freezes and gives a timeout message after some time

Reason for logging in from bash would be complete this:

`keycloak/bin $ ./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE`.

which would hopefully solve the original problem of HTTPS required.

Answer (score 111):

Update Feb 2022:

Keycloak 17+ (e.g. `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0`) doesn't support autogeneration of selfsigned cert. Minimal HTTPS working example for Keycloak 17+:

1.) Generate selfsigned domain cert/key (follow instructions on your terminal):

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes \
  -keyout server.key.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out server.crt.pem
```

2.) Update permissions for the key

```
chmod 755 server.key.pem
```

3.) Start Keycloak (use volumes for cert/key):

```
docker run \
  --name keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password \
  -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/opt/keycloak/conf/server.crt.pem \
  -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/opt/keycloak/conf/server.key.pem \
  -v $PWD/server.crt.pem:/opt/keycloak/conf/server.crt.pem \
  -v $PWD/server.key.pem:/opt/keycloak/conf/server.key.pem \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0 \
  start-dev
```

Keycloak will be exposed on port 8443 with HTTPS protocol with this setup. If you use also proxy (e.g. nginx) you will need to configure also env variable `KC_PROXY` properly (e.g. `KC_PROXY=edge`). Of course you can use also `keycloak.conf` file instead of env variables.

---

Old answer for Keycloak up to 16.1.1 and Keycloak legacy 17+:

Publish port 8443 (HTTPS) and use it instead of 8080 (HTTP):

```
docker run \
  --name keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword \
  -p 8443:8443 \
  jboss/keycloak
```

Keycloak generates self signed cert for https in this setup. Of course, this is not a production setup.

---

Update

Use volumes for own TLS certificate:

```
  -v /<path>/tls.crt:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt \
  -v /<path>/tls.key:/etc/x509/https/tls.key \
```

Comment: when I try to connect to `https://localhost:8443/auth` is not found, any ideas? does it work also with keycloak 2.5.5 ?

Comment: this hint is golden! they should put it in the documentation

Comment: @Edwin Keycloak takes about 1-2 mins to start after the docker container is running

Comment: This doesn't work. Even if you wait 1-2 mins. It's not accesible via `https://localhost:8443`. It's not reachable.

Comment: @Avión don't use `localhost` but IP of your Docker host. I guess you are mixing localhosts from different network namespaces.

Comment: I tested it with the public IP, of course. It's not working for me :(

Comment: @Avión, pls open new question and provide all relevant details there (`curl -v -k https://<IP>:8443/`, `docker logs keycloak`, `docker info`, start command, ....)

Comment: The other solutions (doing the _exec_ which I wanted to avoid) worked, so as it's just for development purposes I will stick to that. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, still stuck with https keycloak.

Comment: this works for me, but how can I work with my own certificates now from there?

Comment: update, thank you for the quick response. Seem to get closer, but now I get the following erros: `Closing SSLConduit after exception on handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common` . My certs have a .pem ending. Does it matter?

Comment: @DataMastery No, it isn't related to cert, but to TLS (client or server) cipher configuration (it is out of the scope this topic).

Comment: For anyone who wants to run TLS via mounting certificate and keyfile into /etc/x509/https directory with a passphrase protected keyfile: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60741019/2799606

Comment: When I'm using 8443 and the self-signed ceritficate can't login into kcadm.sh anymore. how to point to new truststore? Also, can't find the .jks file...

Comment: When copying address, remember to add the s to http. Also some browser might not let you visit the site at all out of security concern and instead will display a warning (e.g Chrome)

Comment: For those who cannot find keycloak on bin go to `opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/`

Comment: If anyone is having trouble getting this to work: make sure that you've HTTPS at the beginning of your address e.g. in the browser. My browser had just localhost:8443 instead of https:// localhost:8443 and it was not working. Simple but annoying to find!

Comment: @Edwin try adding --hostname=<IP> in the end (after start-dev)

Comment: same problem, "Page not found" https://<IP>:8443/auth

Comment: updating permission key solved my problem.

Answer (score 14):

This was a solution that also granted access to the admin console with no security when using https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/ as a starting point and DigitalOcean as service provider:

Start container:

```
$ docker run {containerName}
```

Open bash for container:

```
$ docker exec -it {containerName} bash
```

Move to:

```
$ cd keycloak/bin
```

create new admin user with:

```
$ ./add-user-keycloak.sh --server http://{IP}:8080/admin    
--realm master --user admin --password newpassword
```

(not add-user.sh as suggested in many places)

Restart droplet in DigitalOcean etc. to activated admin user created prior to the shutdown. After restarting the droplet login with:

```
$ ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth 
--realm master --user admin
```

Changing ssl settings on the realm:

```
$ ./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

This solution does not create any security but allows you to access the Admin console.

After this it is suggested to start workin on this:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#setting-up-https-ssl

Comment: This doesnt work because when you run this  ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth
--realm master --user admin   it gives error HTTPS REQUIRED

Answer (score 13):

The following sequence of commands worked for me

On the host VM:

```
docker run --name key -d -p 8080:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
docker exec -it key bash
```

Inside the container:

```
cd keycloak/bin/
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin 
Logging into http://localhost:8080/auth as user admin of realm master
Enter password: admin
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

Comment: thanks that helped me, for my test server. but pls done ever use this on a prod server :D

Comment: work for me on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if someone wants to use it on a Docker Swarm using secrets to store the certificate files and admin credentials:

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak-server
    hostname: keycloak-server
    ports:
      - target: 8443 # Keycloak HTTPS port
        published: 8443
        mode: host
      - target: 8080 # Keycloak HTTP port
        published: 8080
        mode: host
    networks: 
      default:
        aliases: 
          - keycloak-server
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    secrets:
      - keycloak_user_file
      - keycloak_password_file
      - source: server_crt
        target: /etc/x509/https/tls.crt
        uid: '103'
        gid: '103'
        mode: 0440
      - source: server_key
        target: /etc/x509/https/tls.key
        uid: '103'
        gid: '103'
        mode: 0440
    environment: 
      - KEYCLOAK_USER_FILE=/run/secrets/keycloak_user_file
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/keycloak_password_file

secrets:
  server_crt:
    file: ./certs/server.crt
  server_key:
    file: ./certs/server.key
  keycloak_user_file:
    file: ./keycloak/adminuser
  keycloak_password_file:
    file: ./keycloak/adminpassword
```

Comment: note that I could not get the KEYCLOAK_USER_FILE / KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD_FILE secrets to work.  I believe based on this github issue (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/10816) that it is broken in, at least, quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1  Note that the github issue has a workaround of a custom shell script as the entrypoint

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to disable HTTPS, you can with this

```
docker exec -it {contaierID} bash
cd keycloak/bin
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

Answer (score 2):

Update after Jboss/Keyclok 12.0.0

Use following command in the server without login to docker container via bash.

```
$ docker exec <container_id> /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user <admin_username> --password <admin_password>
```

Logging into http://localhost:8080/auth as user admin of realm master

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced bash freezing when trying to config credentials.

Adding the `--password` argument to the `config credentials` command resulted in a successful execution:

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password {YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE}
```

Execute `./kcadm.sh config credentials` for examples of secure/alternate ways to pass the argument.

Answer (score 0):

For cases where Docker was used to build Keycloak. This worked for me:

```sh
docker exec -it demo-keycloak bash
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm realmname --user admin --password admin 
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/realmname -s sslRequired=NONE
```

**Explanation**:
First line gives an interactive bash shell on the Keycloak container.
second and third line authenticates you and makes modification to the realm settings using the Keycloak admin-cli. There is no need for container restart

Answer (score 0):

Finally get it working with https (Keycloak 14.0.0) in the simplest way after trying innumerable ways.

- Create a docker-compose.yml and DO NOT specify the volumes for cert and key:

```
version: '2'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:14.0.0
    command: -c standalone.xml
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: h2
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
```

- Run your docker-compose.yml with *docker-compose up*.
- Wait over a minute and Keycloak will generate a self signed certificate automatically! you´ll see the logs on cli:

*WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (default I/O-3) WFLYDM0113: Generated self signed certificate at /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore. Please note that self signed certificates are not secure, and should only be used for testing purposes. Do not use this self signed certificate in production.*

- Access your Keycloak server on port 8443.
- If you don´t see the logs indicating the generation of the self signed certificate, just try to access your server including *'https://'* and *':8443*', like *'https://your_ip_or_dns:8443/auth'*.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the image you use. If you use the quay.io/keycloak/keycloak. Your must explicitly specify the path that cert and key use `KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE` and `KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE`. A little different from the one jboss.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises because Keycloak is not on the same network as the host machine. By default, Keycloak does not allow HTTP requests from a different network. However, if both were on the same network, it would be possible.

One potential solution would be to map port 8083 instead of 8080, as shown in the example below:

```
docker run -p 8083:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Certificate generation with Lets Encrypt :

- SSH to the Keycloak Server host
- Run the following command to install the Letsencrypt Certbot:

```
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

- Next, run the following command to ensure that the certbot command can now be run:

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

- Now run Certbot to start the certificate generation:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone
```

- Follow the on-screen instructions to generate a SSL/TLS certificate and private key.
- You now have a `fullchain.pem` and a `privkey.pem` file for use with SSL/TLS
- Deploying and Testing the Keycloak Server:

  ```
      sudo docker run \
      --name dev-keycloak \
      -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
      -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password \
      -e KC_HOSTNAME=Your-Host-Name \
      -v /home/bvr/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt \
      -v /home/bvr/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key \
      -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/etc/x509/https/tls.crt \
      -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/etc/x509/https/tls.key \
      -p 8443:8443 \
      quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 \
      start-dev
  ```
- To Access the Admin Console : https://your-host-name