# Keycloak from docker Letsencrypt cert and ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: docker, ssl, certificate, keycloak, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to run Keycloak from a Docker image available on: [Docker Hub here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/). If I run my container using the command:

```
docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=test -v /opt/mountedcertificate:/etc/x509/https -p 8443:8443 jboss/keycloak
```

Setting the volume according to the instruction from previously mentioned website for this image:

> Setting up TLS(SSL) Keycloak image allows you to specify both a
>   private key and a certificate for serving HTTPS. In that case you need
>   to provide two files:
>
> tls.crt - a certificate
>
> tls.key - a private key
>
> Those files need to be
>   mounted in /etc/x509/https directory. The image will automatically
>   convert them into a Java keystore and reconfigure Wildfly to use it.

in /opt/mountedcertificate I have .key and .crt file generated according to the instructions given in this topic:

[Keycloak SSL setup using docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674979/keycloak-ssl-setup-using-docker-image)

The certificate has been issued by certbot from letsencrypt and those files were my starting point for later conversion as stated in the mentioned topic. I know it's the same issue but maybe there turned out to be any solution for this problem.

I'm really desperate after trying a lot of different approaches and searching the Web looking for a working one.

Comment: was someone able to help you or did you solve it? Run into the same problem

Comment: @DataMastery Unfortenately, not, I haven't managed to do it so far :(

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make sure the key file is readable by jboss user inside the docker. Here are some key steps in my solution:

```
1. get cert/key from let's encrypt.
2. change file mode to 655
3. mount them to keycloak:
      - /opt/www/sso/cert/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - /opt/www/sso/cert/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
4. launch docker image
5. change file mode back to 600 for the key file.
```

Here is an example code I'm using:

```
cp ../ssl-certs/etc/live/xxx.cn/*.pem cert/
chmod 644 cert/*
docker-compose -p sso.xxx.cn down
docker-compose -p sso.xxx.cn up -d
sleep 120
chmod 600 cert/*key*
```

Comment: It was better if you added some commands in your explanation

Comment: @AyoubAnbara, just added.