# Cannot connect to keycloak admin panel

Tags: docker, keycloak

I've followed [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak) tutorial and run keycloak with postgres via Docker. Since port 8080 is already in use by my front-end app, it used 9990 instead.
As the logs say:

> 13:26:00,602 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
>
> 13:26:00,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990

But when I go to these urls through my browser, nothing happens. I've also tried going to http://127.0.0.1:9990/auth/admin/ and it doesn't work to. When I try to connect, nothing appears in my keycloak console.

I've followed the tutorial without any additional settings. What's wrong?

Firstly I create a user define network:

> docker network create keycloak-network

Then I run postgres:

> docker run -d --name postgres --net keycloak-network -e POSTGRES_DB=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres

And Finally Keycloak:

> docker run --name keycloak --net keycloak-network jboss/keycloak

Comment: Could you paste commands which you used to start keycloak container?

Comment: @krynio I have edited my post

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to publish ports (8080 for http, 8443 for https) of the Keycloak container + remap ports, because 8080 is already used on your machine. For example:

```
docker run --rm \
  --name keycloak \
  --net keycloak-network \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword \
  -p 9990:8080 \
  -p 9991:8443 \
  jboss/keycloak
```

Keycloak admin UI will be available on:

- `http://<ip of the host machine\>:9990/`
- `https://<ip of the host machine\>:9991/` (self signed cert will be generated in this case, so you will need to approve TLS exception in the browser)

More details about TLS cert in Keycloak: [Keycloak Docker HTTPS required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required/49874353#49874353)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: I second @Desiigner. Brilliant Solution. Command with more customizations

> docker run --rm --name keycloak --net <networkname> -e KEYCLOAK_USER=<keycloakuser> -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=<keycloakpassword> -p 9990:8080 -p 9991:8443 --net <networkname> -e DB_VENDOR=<dbtype ex: postgres> -e JDBC_PARAMS='connectTimeout=30' -e DB_ADDR=<hostname>:<port> -e DB_DATABASE=<dbname> -e DB_SCHEMA=<dbschema> -e DB_USER=<dbuser> -e DB_PASSWORD=<dbpassword> jboss/keycloak

Comment: why this command works just like that but doesnt work when its started via docker compose?

Answer (score 2):

If someone else like me will start his way in Docker from installing Keycloak asap.

Full path to install Keycloak on Docker and then have access to web UI via port 9990 (you can change it in last command):

```
docker network create keycloak-network

docker run -d --name postgres --net keycloak-network -e POSTGRES_DB=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres

docker run --rm --name keycloak --net keycloak-network -e KEYCLOAK_USER=myadmin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=mypassword -e DB_USER=keycloak -e DB_PASSWORD=password -p 9990:8080 -p 9991:8443 jboss/keycloak
```

Difference from topickstarter's and previous answer is avoiding of error below:

```
"WFLYCTL0113: '' is an invalid value for parameter user-name
```

by providing DB username and password in last command.

Comment: This case work for me, thx