# Run Jhipster project as a jar on Ubuntu, and got HTTPS required when login

Tags: ubuntu, jhipster, keycloak

I built a Jhipster project (with SpringBoot and React) into a jar on Mac and ran it without any issue on Mac, and now put it to Ubuntu, and got stuck when the login page comes up (I use **KeyCloak** for login). As I use KeyCloak, and now it shows an **error screen** saying **"Https Required"**.

I searched online and most of the resolutions cannot applied in my case: this is a new Ubuntu box on AWS, and no GUI, so i cannot start the GUI and set it to be not requiring HTTPS for external (which is what I need); and this is KeyCloak bundled with Jhipster, so I cannot find where its database is and so cannot change the policy in the database level; and I run this on Linux from a jar, so I cannot go into the configuration code of Keycloak (if there is any besides the keycloak.yml) to  specify the https-not-required policy. So I am kind of stuck here. I just want to get to the login page from the home, and run like it's on localhost. Please help... Thanks a lot!

Comment: JHipster Keycloak docker file is based on the official one from RedHat and it is well documented https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

Comment: find where Keycloak bin folder is then follow this tutorial second part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059427/1264304

Comment: Thanks Rok. However, this keycloak is 'shipped' with the Jhipter, as my project was created by Jhipster, I cannot find where the Keycloak bin is. In other words, I never installed keycloak in Ubuntu, and only run this keycloak using the command as Jhipster manual says: docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up. So I don't know where to find the bin of keycloak, and the /opt/jboss/keycloak is also empty ...