# Serve Dockerized VueJS app with Nginx cant be accessed and results in SSL Error

Tags: docker, vue.js, ssl, nginx

I try to run a Dockerized VueJS app. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

CMD [ "http-server", "-p 5000", "dist" ]
```

I spin up the container with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 5000:5000 vuejs
```

My default nginx file has this relevant part:

```
server {

    listen                443;
    server_name           data-mastery.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/data-mastery.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/data-mastery.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


       location / {

        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:5000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;

        proxy_redirect    off;
        proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;

    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to access I don´t get redirected and trying to access it with on my port (https://data-mastery.com:5000/) results in an error:

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Another container with runs on port 8443 works fine. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. Your Vue app is available on https://data-mastery.com (LE cert). And port 5000 is occupied by Keycloak (but only http protocol is enabled) - http://data-mastery.com:5000/.

Comment: yep, I figured it out on my own. Has to set just http, not https.

Comment: @DataMastery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required/49874353#49874353

Comment: yes, already made use of this, thank you. Like I said, everything works fine now. Keycloak gets passed to https, my VueJS app to http. Keycloak runs on a subpage: analytics.data-mastery.com:8443