# How can I add ssl to private task in AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, keycloak, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to deploy a keycloak docker container as a Fargate Task in AWS. The Task starts and the keycloak landing page is available for http port 8080, but I need to configure port 8443 for ssl. The only solution I know of is to assign domain to keycloak load balancer. But I do not want to use load balancer and instead will use it as a private container. Is there a way to do that without running load balancer?

Comment: Do you want a self-signed certificate for private use, within your VPC?

Comment: Yes exactly, self signed certificate can work, but since I don't know what will be the private ip address I can't generate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official Keycloak Docker image generates own self-signed cert and uses it for HTTPS protocol, which is exposed on the port 8443. So just connect to the 8443 port.

Reference: [Keycloak Docker HTTPS required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required/49874353#49874353)

Comment: Thank you, the reason it didn't work for me I was exposing both 8080 and 8443

Answer (score 0):

For self-signed certificates you do not need to associate them with an IP address. Just generate them and deploy. Usually for that you use **nginx as a reverse proxy** in a sidecar configuration to your main container.

How to use nginx in such setup is shown in the recent the following AWS blog post:

- [Deploying an NGINX Reverse Proxy Sidecar Container on Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nginx-reverse-proxy-sidecar-container-on-amazon-ecs/)

In this setup you will be connecting to nginx which will be serving https connection via self-signed certification.

There is many tutorials on line how to setup nginx and generate self-signed certificates. For example:

- [How to Create a Self-Signed SSL/TLS Certificate for Nginx in 5 Minutes](https://www.humankode.com/ssl/create-a-selfsigned-certificate-for-nginx-in-5-minutes)
- [How to Create a Self-Signed Certificate for Nginx in Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2019/06/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: If I would deploy nginx I can have load balancer. The reason I want to do that it is to prevent unnecessary charges