# Keycloak Admin Console requires HTTPS when connected remotely (Should I disable SSL)

Tags: keycloak

I am connecting to Keycloak remotely. And when  I try to open the Admin Console, I get an error saying **HTTPS required**.

In one of the websites, it says that I should do this: `"update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where id = 'master';"`

But I do not know the consequences of doing this. Will this make it unsecure? Or can I reverse this?

Thank you

(And If I would run Keycloak within a docker image would this problem be solved?)

Comment: The recommended setting in production is `ssl-required="all"`, for other environments you should always set at least `ssl-required="external"`. Based on what you say I'll assume that if you access your Keycloak console on the HTTPS port, it works. So its very good practice. Not enforcing HTTPS will make things unsecure as your token(s) may be stolen f.i.

Comment: Have you resolved the above? I’m running into ECS fargate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admim console uses open id connect protocol, which needs HTTPS to be secure. So it isn't good idea to disable ssl in the prod environment.

Keycloak in the container doesn't solve your problem. But it provides user friendly approach to generate selfsigned cert - [Keycloak Docker HTTPS required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required/49874353#49874353)

Secure option is to generate valid TLS certificate and use it in your Keycloak instance, so you have valid secure TLS/HTTPS connection.

Comment: But in that answer you specified that this was not a production setup. I need this for  a production phase.

Comment: And can I ask what does this mean                                                                             
 "Use volumes for own TLS certificate:

  -v /<path>/tls.crt:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt \
  -v /<path>/tls.key:/etc/x509/https/tls.key \"

Comment: @pigwidgeon doc is your friend https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/