# Keycloak. How change Administration Console Domain?

Tags: docker, keycloak

In docker mode https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

`docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=<USERNAME> -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD> jboss/keycloak`

All working only via `localhost:8080`

If we try to access https://custom.com/auth/admin/master/console, we get a white page (access only from localhost).

How change domain to custom.com? (in documentations only change file, but in docker not have possible. Need stateless solutions)

Any idea without mounting file.

Comment: Do you resolve custom.com as localhost?

Comment: I would start with https https://stackoverflow.com/a/49874353/3348604

Comment: And if KeyCloak runs behind Reverse Proxy you need
 -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true

Answer (score 0):

Need add `-e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` for access to keyloack admin from https://custom.com (not localshost:8080)