# How do I configure Keycloak and get a JWT with all steps done through the REST API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I need to configure Keycloak running in Docker with a realm, a user with credentials, and a client and then get a JWT as in this [blog post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak/).  If I use the UI as shown it works, but I need to automate all steps through the Keycloak REST API.  When I do that all steps seem to work but getting a JWT fails.

I run Keycloak in Docker like this

```
docker network create keycloak-network

docker run --name mysql -d \
  --net keycloak-network \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak \
  -e MYSQL_USER=keycloak \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password \
  mysql:8.0.22

docker run -d -it \
  -e DB_VENDOR=mysql \
  -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
  --name keycloak \
  --net keycloak-network \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  jboss/keycloak:11.0.3
```

I obtain an access token from the master realm

```
POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "username=admin" -d "password=admin" -d "grant_type=password" -d 'client_id=admin-cli' "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"|jq -r '.access_token'
```

Then I create my realm (named `testrealm`)

```
POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @"${REALM_FILE}" "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms"
```

Then I create a user with credentials:

```
POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/users" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" -d {"enabled":true,"username":"testuser","email":"test.user@gmail.com","firstName":"test","lastName":"user","credentials":[{"type":"password","value":"abc123","temporary":false}]}
```

I can see the new user in the UI and an entry in the new users credentials with Type password.

I create a client (named `testclient`)

```
POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @"${CLIENT_FILE}" "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/clients"
```

I get the necessary ids to modify the new client with

```
GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/authentication/flows"
```

extracting the BROWSER_ID from the Alias `browser` and the DIRECT_GRANT_ID from the Alias `direct grant`.

I update the client changing the `Access Type` to `confidential` and with `Authentication Flow Overrides` for `Browser Flow` and `Direct Grant Flow`

```
PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @client.update.json "http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/clients/${clientId}"
```

where the data is

```
{                                                                               
    "publicClient": false,        
    "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",                                            
    "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {                                                                 
        "direct_grant":"${DIRECT_GRANT_ID}",
        "browser":"${BROWSER_ID}"
    }
}
```

I get the client secret with

```
GET -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/testrealm/clients/${CLIENT_ID}/client-secret
```

At this point if I go into the UI it shows the same client secret that I get back and that the client `Access Type` is `confidential` and the `Authentication Flow Overrides` were set to `browser` and `direct grant`.  Everything looks correct.  The Keycloak server should now be configured the same as when done through the UI as shown in the post.

When I use the curl command as shown in the post to get a JWT

```
curl -L -X POST http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'client_id=testclient' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=544479de-72a4-44c7-9420-3a142cd699c6' --data-urlencode 'scope=openid' --data-urlencode 'username=testuser' --data-urlencode 'password=abc123'
```

gives an error saying that https is required.

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"HTTPS required"}
```

But https is not required when the configuration was done through the UI.  In fact all requests have been sent through http, not https.

Then using https

```
curl -L -X POST https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'client_id=testclient' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=544479de-72a4-44c7-9420-3a142cd699c6' --data-urlencode 'scope=openid' --data-urlencode 'username=testuser' --data-urlencode 'password=abc123'
```

I get this error

```
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

If I configure Keycloak through the UI the curl command works so I must have missed something when using the `REST API`.  The Keycloak docs don't show this use case so they are no help here.

Does anyone know what I've missed when using the `REST API`?

Comment: When changing from http to https I should have changed the port to 8443.  That port has to be shared from docker as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish port 8443 of the Keycloak container. There will be https with self signed cert (so disable tls verification in your requests):

```
docker run -d -it \
 -e DB_VENDOR=mysql \
 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
 --name keycloak \
 --net keycloak-network \
 -p 8443:8443 \
 jboss/keycloak:11.0.3
```

Keycloak will be available on `https://localhost:8443`. See [Keycloak Docker HTTPS required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required/49874353#49874353)

Comment: Good catch.  This still leaves the mystery of why when I configure through the UI I can use port 8080 but when I configure with the REST API I have to use port 8443.