# Add Letsencrypt Certificate to Keycloak Trusted Certificates

Tags: docker, ssl, certificate, keycloak

We have the following setup:

- A Keycloak Server on a VM installed as a docker container.
- Server certificate via Lets Encrypt.
- Two realms a and b.
- Realm b is integrated into Realm a as an identity provider.

To achieve that it works, we had to import the certificate of the Keycloak server into the java trusted store. Now the login works and we can choose in realm a if we want to login with realm b. Unfortunately the process of importing the certificate comes with lots of manual effort (copy the certificate into the container, divide the chain into several files with only one certificate, call a function) and the certificates are just valid for 90 days. Of course we can automate this but the question is, is there an "official way" of doing this? Like mounting the Lets Encrypt certificate folder into the container and "done"? We are using the official jboss/keycloak container image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak Docker HTTPS required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required)

Comment: No, that seems to be a totally different  topic (using keycloack with https)

Comment: Nope, you have examples how to use volumes for tls certs there = your "Like mounting the Lets Encrypt certificate folder into the container and done"

Comment: But the certificates in the example are for the keycloak instance I want add certificates to the trusted key storey

Answer (score 0):

The docker container should support this by setting the `X509_CA_BUNDLE` variable accordingly. See the [docs here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/tree/17.0.0/server#user-content-setting-up-tlsssl).

This creates the truststore for you and configures it in Wildfly. Details can be found in [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/17.0.0/server/tools/x509.sh#L66) and [that](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/17.0.0/server/tools/cli/x509-truststore.cli) script.