# Setting up HTTPS/SSL for Keycloak 17+

Tags: keycloak

Does Keycloak 17 and above powered by Quarkus distribution has **standalone mode**?
The [keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting_up_ssl) says, that i can still use it, to setting up HTTPS/SSL. In the documentation there is a procedure, to edit the *standalone.xml* file, that no longer exist in this new version of keycloak.

Does standalone mode still exist? Or is there a different documentation in this not deprecated, new version that should be used? How to set up HTTPS/SSL then?

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config?q=https

Use these parameters to customize TLS configuration based on your needs:

```
https-certificate-file

The file path to a server certificate or certificate chain in PEM format.

https-certificate-key-file

The file path to a private key in PEM format.

https-cipher-suites

The cipher suites to use.

https-client-auth

Configures the server to require/request client authentication.

https-key-store-file

The key store which holds the certificate information instead of specifying separate files.

https-key-store-password

The password of the key store file.

https-key-store-type

The type of the key store file.

https-port

The used HTTPS port.

https-protocols

The list of protocols to explicitly enable.

https-trust-store-file

The trust store which holds the certificate information of the certificates to trust.

https-trust-store-password

The password of the trust store file.

https-trust-store-type

The type of the trust store file.
```

Container deployement has also support for TLS, see [Keycloak Docker HTTPS required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required/49874353#49874353)